# Does SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access preserve the table relationship?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, migration

I was just migrating the Access database to SQL Server. I was really happy about the fact that it preserves primary key ,sets up auto-increment etc. However, looks like it does not preserve the table relationship. Did I do something wrong while migrating or is there no relationship preservation feature?

Comment: What do you mean by 'table relationship'?

Comment: It is called Database diagrams in SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Ah, yes.  Well, I guess you do lose that.  It's more of a graphical convenience.  It's not really a 'hard' setting, like you have with the schemas.  I can't think of any setting or control that would preserve those relationships, especially because it's graphical and there can be an infinite number of combinations.  I suppose you can re-create those pretty easily, especially if you have 2 monitors, right.